# Present simple with future meaning

Tags: grammar, present-simple, future-time

I was studying Grammar in Use, Unit 19. It says that:"You can use the present simple to talk about people if their plans are fixed like a timetable."

So assume that I've decided to study one unit each day, can I say this: "I study unit 20 tomorrow."

Comment: Yes, you can say it. But it would require context to be meaningful.  For example, if a friend had asked you when you would study unit 20, the answer would be fine. We say things like: **I leave for London next week** and **I fly to Canada on Friday**, nearly always as part of a conversation about our intentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible in context, if you want to make a particular point.

Normally you would say "I'll study unit 20 tomorrow".  This is *unmarked*, it makes a simple statement about the future. This might be a plan or a prediction.

However, if you want to emphasise the strict inflexibility of the schedule, you may use the simple present, with a time expression like "tomorrow".  This is *marked*, it makes a particular point. So don't use it unless you are making the point that the timetable *cannot* be changed.

It would be unusual in your context, since you have decided to study one unit a day, and I would expect that you are able to change your mind, so the timetable *can* be changed.